# Jquery validation not working for special characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, client-side-validation

I am writing jquery validation to make a strong password. I wrote condition for special characters and it is not working. I am trying as below.

```
"regex": /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$])[0-9a-zA-Z]{8,}$/,
"alertText": "*Password should contain atleast one special character,one number and one upper case letter",
```

I am having trouble with `(?=.*[!@#$])` part of code. If I remove this regular expression will work but it will not validate special characters. If I put `(?=.*[!@#$])` nothing it will validate. Always I am getting an error popup. I am not sure about `(?=.*[!@#$])` this part.

Comment: Add the `!@#$` to the character class at the end.

Comment: Keep in mind that this JS code is only used on the client and is easily disabled. You need to ALSO check the password on the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your consuming character class at the end of the pattern (`[0-9a-zA-Z]`) does not match the special chars that you require with the `(?=.*[!@#$])` lookahead. Add those `!@#$` chars there:

```
"regex": /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$])[0-9a-zA-Z!@#$]{8,}$/
                                                               ^^^^
```

Comment: Working like charm. Thank you.